# Mobile Application Development Framework

Tags: mobile, widget

I am looking for an mobile development framework, using which I can develop application like widgets for any mobile. I found Yahoo Blueprints. But for this I need to expose my server to internet. Are there any such frameworks like Yahoo blueprints, through which I can develop mobile widgets.

Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do cross platform application development, your best bet is to use something like [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/).  Then you can use a combination of HTML, JavaScript and native code to create applications.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link.  I see that they have an excellent "getting started" tutorial for Blackberry app development.